# Replace checkbox with String for Booleans in DefaultTableCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jtable, boolean, tablecellrenderer

I've been trying to learn JTable renderers, and have nearly nailed down the behavior I'm looking for, save for this last part. I want to remove the checkbox that JTable renders by default for booleans and render a simple String instead, and I just can't wrap my head around my problem here.

Since my changes to the renderer are very minor (only basic String operations, plus a foreground color for booleans), I want to extend `DefaultTableCellRenderer` instead of implementing `TableCellRenderer` and going from scratch. *I also have been using the same renderer for all cell types since it seemed silly to create a new class for each one of my simple operations.* Here's my relevant code:

```
public class MyTableRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public MyTableRenderer() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if(value instanceof Boolean) {
            boolean v = (boolean) value;
            setForeground( v ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED );
            setText( v ? "Alive" : "Dead" );
        }
    /*  else if(value instanceof //Other types, and so on and so forth */

    }

}
```

I'm applying the renderer to the table as such:

```
JTable myTable = new JTable(myTableModel);
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableRenderer());
```

I've ensured that my table model responds to `getColumnClass()` properly, and my renderer behaves as it should for all other types of `value`, only Boolean is acting up. No matter what I `setText` to in the event of a Boolean value, my text is replaced by the default checkbox. **I understand that Boolean values use a separate renderer by default, but shouldn't calling** `setDefaultRenderer` **on** `Object.class` **override the default for** `Boolean.class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableRenderer());
```

You are creating a Boolean renderer, not an Object renderer. So you should be using:

```
myTable.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, new MyTableRenderer());
```

> but shouldn't calling setDefaultRenderer on Object.class override the default for Boolean.class?

No. The Object renderer is used as the default renderer if there is no renderer specified for a specific class. Since there is a default Boolean renderer you will use that renderer, unless you replace the renderer with one of your own.

> I also have been using the same renderer for all cell types since it seemed silly to create a new class for each one of my simple operations

Without knowing exactly what you are doing, in general, you should be creating custom renderers. Any time you see if/else logic in code you know you have a design problem. Use the features provided by JTable and create renderers for each class of data instead of using if/else.

If you think you have a lot of common rendering logic then you create a renderer with the common rendering code. Then you create multiple renderers that extend your base renderer for each class of data you want to support.

> I'm trying to use this same renderer for all cell types,

Well that is the problem as I was stating above.

If you really have a good reason for doing this then you also need to add the line of code I suggest above for all classes of data that you want to share the same renderer. At least you need to do that for the classes that have default renderers.

Comment: Well, no, I'm trying to use this same renderer for all cell types, Boolean or otherwise. Sorry if I didn't make that clear. Do I have to create a separate Boolean renderer in addition to my general-purpose renderer?